# jQuery append div in a div to the bottom of a scroll window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying all the stuff I read here and all over the net, but it looks like I am not getting it somehow.

I have been [fiddling it](http://jsfiddle.net/nejnio/r3R4a/8/) for a while but still it does not work.

```
<div id="blokscubes" class='main'> 
<div id="alldivs">
</div>
<div id="report" class="mydivs"></div>
```

```
$('#report').text('One');
  for (i=1;i < 11;i++){    
     var newid = 'report-' + i.toString();
     var oldid = '#report-' + (i-1).toString();
     $('#alldivs').append('<div id=' + newid +  ' class="mydivs">'+ newid + '</div>');
     var hashold = '#' + newid;
     $(hashold).animate({"scrollTop": $(hashold)[0].scrollHeight}, 300);

     $(oldid).css('position','relative');
  }
```

The last added div always hangs to the bottom of the screen,but not to the bottom of the scrolled down screen.

What am I missing or not writing correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how related this is to your problem and I am certainly not sure what you are trying to achieve but the `scrollTop` animation is not allowed to finish before you've iterated to the next `i++`

Comment: Do you want the last Element to stay at a fixed position, just hovering at the bottom of the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the last `div` has `position:absolute` instead of `relative`.

You can set the CSS to have the `mydivs` have a `relative` position, or you can set the last `div` created to have `position:relative` (You missed the last one out)

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/8H6kf/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you first set `position:absolute` for `.mydiv` and then via js you change to `position: relative`. Problem is that your last div has still absolute position. You can fix this like this:

```
$('#report-1').text('One');
$('#report-1').css('position','relative');   

    for (i=2;i < 10;i++){    
        var newid = 'report-' + i.toString();
        var oldid = '#report-' + (i-1).toString();
        $('#blokscubes').append('<div id=' + newid +  ' class="mydivs">'+ newid + '</div>');
        var hashold = '#' + newid;
        $(hashold).animate({"scrollTop": $(hashold)[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");

        $('#' + newid).css('position','relative');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `position:fixed` on the last Element, relative to a parent that you should surround `$('#blokscubes')` with, and create a height on a new empty second to last Element, so there is no word over word overlap. Note that `position:fixed` and `position:absolute` are `relative` to the closest parent that is `position:relative` or the `document.documentElement` *(html tag)*, which is `position:static`. So, you basically have your positioning wrong. Also, there is usually no need to create non-dynamic Elements with jQuery. Just use HTML and CSS.